# Can't create google_storage_bucket via Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to create the following resource via Terraform:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "tf_state_bucket" {
  name          = var.bucket-name
  location      = "EUROPE-WEST3"
  storage_class = "STANDARD"
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  force_destroy = false
  public_access_prevention = "enforced"
}
```

Unfortunately, during the execution of `terraform apply`, I got the following error:
`googleapi: Error 403: X@gmail.com does not have storage.buckets.create access to the Google Cloud project. Permission 'storage.buckets.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., forbidden`

Here's the list of things I tried and checked:

1. Verified that Google Cloud Storage (JSON) API is enabled on my project.
2. Checked the IAM roles and permissions: X@gmail.com has the Owner and the Storage Admin roles.
3. I can create a bucket manually via the Google Console.
4. Terraform is generally authorised to create resources, for example, I can create a VM using it.

What else can be done to authenticate Terraform to create Google Storage Buckets?

Comment: Where do you launch the Terraform code ? From a `Shell` session and you local machine ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you run the `Terraform` code in a `Shell` session from your local machine and use an `User` identity instead of a `Service Account` identity.

In this case to solve your issue from your local machine :

- Create a Service Account in `GCP` `IAM` console for Terraform with `Storage Admin roles` role.
- Download a Service Account token key from `IAM`.
- Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var in your `Shell` session to the Service Account token key file path.

If you run your `Terraform` code in other place, you need to check if `Terraform` is correctly authenticated to `GCP`.

The use of a token key is not recommended because it's not the more secure way, that's why it is better to launch `Terraform` from a CI tool like `Cloud Build` instead of launch it from your local machine.
From `Cloud Build` no need to download and set a token key.